# Hibernate Search - specify two types of searches on the same field of a class

Tags: hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

If I specify two types of searches (matching and fuzzy) on the same field of a class like the following:

```
  QueryBuilder qb = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(User.class).get();
  qb.bool().should(qb.keyword().onField("name").matching(searchQuery).createQuery())
     .should(qb.keyword().fuzzy().withPrefixLength(1).onField("name").matching(searchQuery).createQuery());
```

Will the search above end up being:

```
MATCHING searchQuery against "name" OR Fuzzy searchQuery against "name"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you may be missing a `createQuery()` at the end, but otherwise, looks reasonable enough to me, but you can always check for yourself.  Once you have created the final query, just use the [`Query.toString()`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_5_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/Query.html#toString%28%29) method, which should give you a human readable representation of the query, provided you are reasonably familiar with Lucene query parser syntax.  Like:

```java
QueryBuilder qb = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(User.class).get();
Query query = qb.bool()
    .should(qb.keyword().onField("name").matching(searchQuery).createQuery())
    .should(qb.keyword().fuzzy().withPrefixLength(1).onField("name").matching(searchQuery).createQuery())
.createQuery();

System.out.println(query.toString())
//Or however you like to output debugging information...
```